# Change in transformer efficiency (leading power factor) with increasing load current

Tags: transformer, electromagnetism, copper, core

Does efficiency increase or decrease when the load current increases (assuming copper losses equal iron losses along with a leading power factor load)?

Answer (score 1):

> Does efficiency increase or decrease when load current increases
>   (assuming copper losses equal iron losses, leading power factor load)?

The simple scenario of zero load current has to imply that output power is zero therefore power efficiency MUST be zero. So, taking a little bit of load current MUST cause efficiency to increase because you have an actual output power (assuming the load is resistive).

If the load is leading by 90 degrees then under no circumstances will power be consumed therefore efficiency has to always equal zero.

However, if the load is somewhere between resistive and capacitive (i.e. complex) then any current taken will produce an output power and therefore efficiency can be seen to increase.

At some point there will always be turn-down of power efficiency but without a real scenario with a fully defined transformer equivalent circuit and load it's hard to say where this turn-around will occur.

Answer (score 0):

Core losses are not load-dependent, only voltage-dependent (so one cannot assume that core losses and copper losses are equal for different currents). This core-loss term means low efficiency at low current, which is quickly rising with the current.

Copper losses increase proportional with the square of the current, which means that this copper-loss term reduces efficiency with increasing currents, especially for currents larger than the nominal operating point (but the effect is typically not very strong).

Therefore, transformer efficiency rises with the current to a maximum (typically nominal operation point), and then (slowly) falls again with further rising currents.

Answer (score -1):

You need to be crystal clear on two facts before you reach to the conclusion.

i) if you increase load current then definately output voltage across the load will increase.Thus the output power should increase.

but wait a second this isn't the whole thing...

ii) when output current increases then the flux linking the secondary winding also increases.This flux has a tendency to oppose the main flux linking throughout the the core.Thus main flux decreases momentarily.In order to maintain constant main flux the primary drives an extra current that is just sufficient to counter the flux created by seconday winding.

**Conclusion** : if you increase load current  then input current also increases thus copper loss also increases and hence efficiency falls.